# Merge array and join similar items to one item

Tags: javascript

I am creating a recipes app (in React Native) for a big foodblog. In the app, there is an extra tool: an interactive groceries list.

When you open a recipe, you can press a button to fill this groceries list. Eg. if you need 1 pumpkin and 2 pounds of butter, you can press a button and the app will automatically create 2 items in the groceries list: "1 pumpkin" and "2 pounds butter".

The problem I'm facing: let's say you want to add a second recipe to the groceries list, and this recipe also needs 1 pumpkin. Now, the app will just push an item again "1 pumpkin", so you now have 2 items "1 pumpkin" in the groceries list. I don't want tis: I want that those items are merged so it becomes one item saying "2 pumpkins".

I have really no clue how to start. The website is a Wordpress website and I'm using the plugin Advanced Custom Fields to create an extra field for the groceries list. This field is exposed in the REST API and is used by the app only. It's a text field and every line represents one item on the groceries list.

Here is an example with 3 arrays I want to merge to create the merged array:

```
const arr1 = [
  '1 pumpkin',
  '2 pounds of butter',
  'salt'
];

const arr2 = [
  '1 pumpkin',
  'salt'
];

const arr3 = [
  '2 pumpkins',
  '1 jar of peanut butter',
  '1 pound of butter'
];

// mergeArrays() is a custom function I need to create
// this function should detect the different items of the
// groceries list
const mergedArray = mergeArrays(arr1, arr2, arr3);

// resulted array
// mergedArr = [
//   '3 pumpkins',
//   'salt',
//   '3 pounds of butter',
//   '1 jar of peanut butter'
// ];
```

Please note that this is just an example. I can't 'hard code' the word pumpkin because in real life, there are 10 thousands of different products you can need for a recipe and I can't hard code them all.

Comment: Please show what you've got so far, explain how it fails and we can surely help.

Comment: so it should be '4 pumpkins' in the example, right?
the data is not great for what you want to do. better would be something like: ['pumkin': 3]. If you cannot modify this basis. I would start with regex to seperate count and name. then use levenstein or similar to find matching names